# How to remove leading and trailing space from Date formatted cell

Tags: excel, date

I am exploring excel features and trying find whether Excel by default removes trailing spaces when a date is entered.

I know we can do this by adding data validation but is there any other way? I want to remove leading and trailing spaces from existing excel dataset without writing a Marcos or using Trim & Clean.

Appreciate all your help in advance.

Comment: A date is a number, not text.

Comment: From a quick test - if there's no leading spaces then it removes any trailing spaces you may have added, if there's leading spaces it will format the date as text and retain and trailing spaces. Substitute the spaces for no space and multiply the value by 1 to turn back to a number (which can then be formatted as a date).